# PHP handling data POSTED via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I need to loop through some data that was posted to a PHP page through AJAX. I've read about a dozen answers here and none are working for me. This is what my data object looks like before the post:

```
{"sessionValues":[{"ProductID":"507","State":"CHECKED"}, {"ProductID":"204","State":"UNCHECKED"}]}
```

I then post it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'setSessionValues.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {"session" : JSON.stringify(postObj)},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);  //  Hello worldData: , Data: ,          
    }
});
```

This is the last thing that I tried in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["session"])) {
  echo "Hello world";
  $session = json_decode($_POST["session"]);
  echo "Data: " . $session->sessionValues[0]->ProductID . ", " . $session->sessionValues[0]->State;
  $session = json_decode($_POST["session"], true);
  echo "Data: " . $session['sessionValues'][0]['ProductID'] . ", " . $session['sessionValues'][0]['State'];
}
```

Everything I've tried either throws out blanks or errors.

**Edit:**

Turns out that it doesn't like my data. Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

The second thing (xdebug is the first one) you should have tried in PHP is

```
if (isset($_POST["session"])) {
  $session = json_decode($_POST["session"]);
  print_r($session);
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. It's just blank.

Comment: @user1601513 check what's sent in browser devtools then. It is impossible that data being sent correctly, got into PHP's `$_POST` and `json_decode()` fails to decode JSON

Comment: `echo count($_POST["session"]);` also shows nothing. Maybe that explains why after several hours I can't access any data :) I'm at a loss here.

Comment: 1. with browser devtools make sure ajax POST have a payload; 2. with `print_r($_POST)` make sure everything is getting to PHP side

Comment: It doesn't like the syntax of the data. Unexpected end of input.